# Shortest path as a linear program

Tags: graphs, optimization, shortest-path, linear-programming

I just encountered this formulation of the shortest $s$-$t$ path problem as a linear program in a homework. I don't understand exactly the meaning of the variables and restrictions. Here, $G = (V, E)$ is an undirected graph with non-negative weights $w_e$. $S'$ is the set of all cuts in $G$ and $M(S)$ is the set of all edges in the cut $S$.

Primal:
$$\min\sum_{e \in E} w_e x_e$$ s.t.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{e \in M(S)}x_e \geq 1,\quad \forall S \in S'\\
x_e \geq 0, \quad \forall e \in E
\end{align*}

Dual:
$$\max \sum_{S \in S'}y_S$$
s.t.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{S\in S': e\in M(S) } y_S &\geq w_e, \quad \forall e \in E\\
y_S &\geq 0, \quad \forall S \in S'
\end{align*}

For the primal problem, I think that the restrictions enforce that the existence of a path but, I'm not sure why $w_e$ is multiplied by $x_e$. For the dual, I have no idea what $y_S$ might represent.

Comment: Your dual has infinite objective value. Perhaps you meant $\leq w_e$?

Comment: The primal objective is just the total weight of edges in the path. The variables $x_e$ encode the path. You multiply $x_e$ by $w_e$ to get $w_e$ if $e$ is part of the path, and $0$ otherwise. Summing over all edges, you get the total weight of the path.